# How to move several files in different directories to one unique directory?

Tags: command-line, files

I have 220 directories, each one with 2 files inside. all the files have the same termination (*.fq.gz). I want to move all these files to one unique directory.

I think I could do tha with a shell loop, but I don't have idea how to do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. You can do this task with two for loops. One inside the other.
We will create a bash script to do just that.
Let's see how it would look like:

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in */; do
  echo "$dir"
  cd "$dir"
  for file in *; do
    echo "moving $file" 
    mv $file ~/targetdir    
  done
  cd ..
done
```

If you want to have a faster script just remove the echoing from the script.
I made this to make it easy for tracking its progress.

Just create a file and copy these commands to it. After that, give it execution permission with `chmod +x scriptfile` and run it with `./scriptfile` in the main directory where the other directories are located. Don't forget to replace targetdir and scriptfile with your target directory and script file name.

If you have more files in your directories, just replace `*` with `*.fq.gz` in the `for file` loop and it will iterate only through your 2 files.

**Warning!!! Don't create your target directory inside the main directory because it will iterate inside it as well.**

---

Edit: as @steeldriver suggested, you could remove `for dir` commands and just use `for file` commands with`*/*.fq.gz` to have a faster loop. I decided to mantain them for better tracking of whats going on inside directories.

Edit: While doing some research on man and web pages of find and xarg commands answered by @waltinator, I found it more convenient, faster and safe. I even found an alternative to xarg by using the -exec option of the find command such as `find . -type f -name '*.fq.gz' -exec mv --backup=numbered --target-directory=$dest {} \;`.

Comment: Another warning... make absolutely sure that `~/targetdir` exists (and is a directory) otherwise your script will repeatedly overwrite the same file, potentially destroying all but the last one

Comment: As well, the outer loop and `cd` aren't really necessary - you might just as well do `for file in */*` or `for file in */*.fq.gz`. And don't forget to quote `$file` (as you did for `"$dir"`).

Comment: Fully agree with @steeldriver, better to use `mv -t target file`

Comment: .... or at least add a trailing slash to the target so that `mv` will fail if it's not a directory

Comment: Thanks! You were very clear and your code was very helpfull

Answer (score 2):

This is something I use when I don't need to be extra careful

```
mkdir unique_dir && mv */*.fq.gz unique_dir/
```

Unless I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with many files, or files with funny names, `find` and `xargs` are the tools to use. Read `man find;man xargs` and do something like:

```
dest=../destination # must be outside this directory tree
mkdir $dest

find . -type f -name '*.fq.gz' -print0 |\
   xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty echo mv --backup=numbered --target-directory=$dest
```

After you're happy with the results, replace "`echo mv`" with just "`mv`".

To exclude the `$dest` is in current directory difficulty, use `--prune`:

```
find . -type d -name "$dest" -prune -o -type f -name '*.fq.gz' -print0 |\
   xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty echo mv --backup=numbered --target-directory=$dest
```

Comment: you could exclude dest from find.

Answer (score 0):

```
krusader can search files and save to a custom tab then you can select all of those (or filter the list) and move them to the destination

sudo apt install krusader
```

you might as well add

```
sudo apt install krename
```

go to the topmost source directory
tools, search or crtl+s
click feed to listbox
edit select all
file, copy to other panel or f5
other panel being the other tab which is the source target